# Rank of a matrix with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

I have the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
b+3 & a & 4 & -2b-1\\
b & -3 & 5 & -6\\
-1 & 1 & 2a+1 & 1-a
\end{pmatrix}$$

How can I determine the rank for different values of $a$ and $b$? My initial approach was to simplify the matrix by performing elementary row/column operations. In particular, multiplying the last column with two and adding the third to it:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
b+3 & a & 4 & -4b+2\\
b & -3 & 5 & -7\\
-1 & 1 & 2a+1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$

From there, I could conclude that the rank is at least 2, since it has a non-zero minor $M_{2,3}^{2,4}$:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
-3 & -7 \\
1 & 3
\end{vmatrix} = -2$$

Expanding the minor by one row and column yields two $3 \times 3$ minors, but neither of them gets me a reasonably simple expression.
I also tried to transform the matrix into row echelon form, but the values get complicated, which makes it hard to check the special cases one by one. Any ideas?